# Is there an better way to get code from an internal cocoapod into a project?

Tags: git, cocoapods

We currently mange our internal code that is shared between projects using cocoaPods.  The current process for getting a change in a pod to a project that is using it is tedious:

1. Update the pod source code
2. Update the podspec version number (e.g. 0.8.4)
3. Commit and push
4. Tag the commit with 0.8.4
5. In the internal podspecs repo, create a new folder called 0.8.4
6. Copy the podspec from the pod soruce to the new folder.
7. Commit and push the internal podspec.
8. In the project, update the podfile pod `'MyInternalPod', '~> 0.8.4'`
9. Run `pod install`

[image: Pod setup]

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally when targeting an internal pod that is being developed at the same time as the project you should use the newest commit of the master branch. To do this you can just point to the git URL of the repo containing the dependency ([docs](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#pod)). This lets you use the newest commit from the other library without particularly updating it. You just need to run `pod update` whenever you push a new commit and you're all set. Note that this also assumes you're not changing the file structure of the pod in some way that breaks your includes in the last podspec you created for it.

Comment: Reading the docs I believe you don't even need a podspec repo.  The podfile can point directly to the internal pod as long as the podspec is in the top level directory.

Comment: The current version of the docs makes no mention of `:head`. Is there an alternative?